# What command-line text editors come bundled with macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line, text-editor

When I walk up to a Mac, and open a Terminal.app window, what options do I have for editing text files?

I see that both [*Pico*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pico_(text_editor)) and [*GNU nano*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano) text editors are included with macOS Sierra, along with [*vi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) and [*Emacs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs), but apparently not the *ee* text editor bundled in FreeBSD.

What other options for command-line text editors are built into macOS?

- [Pico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pico_(text_editor))
- [GNU nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano)
- [vi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi)
- [Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs)

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve here? Homebrew probably has a whole bunch of editors, others you can compile yourself.

Comment: I was simply asking for a list of bundled command-line text editors. I want to walk up to a Mac and edit files. How is this an unclear Question?

Comment: It‘s unclear because there seems to be a problem behind the problem, somehow. You already know of some editors so you can walk up to any Mac and edit files. If you look for a specific one, it‘s either there or you can add it through Homebrew, install a prebuilt binary or build it yourself. So which problem does get solved by having answers pointing out additional pre-installed text editors?

Comment: @patrix  Choice? I have to say, your decision to close this Question and the ensuing comments leave me mystified.

Comment: Your question gathered more "keep closed" than "reopen" votes in the reopen queue. Nevertheless I've made my fellow mods aware of the question to get another opinion on this.

Comment: `Pico` is just a symlink to `nano`, `vi` is actually `vim` and not counting `awk` or `psed` `cat` `xargs` constructions thats about it. Three CLI text editors are the default.

Comment: @LangLangC Wow, those points would make for a very interesting Answer.

Comment: Thx. And I think it is an interesting question. But answering it: That is not possible while it is on hold. I once actually trawled through /bin and /usr/bin; it is quite a barren landscape compared to a real UNIX or Linux. If your goal is not a simple but easy editor, you really have to familiarise yourself with the most quickest way to install your preferred one. Or get by with nano. Learning vim or mastering emacs is of course the sure-fire way to get around anywhere, methinks (without having a preference for either ;)

Comment: Yes, [*GNU nano*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano) is the way to go for a simple editor on a Mac, now that I know the [*Pico*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pico_(text_editor)) project is deceased and FreeBSD’s *ee* editor is not included. Thanks.

Comment: To the mods: This is interesting, not only for 'what can I do at an Apple Store like setup computer' but also if a someone, e.g. an SE-expert, is summoned for support and has to make do with what he finds. Arbitrary installation of one's fav editor might not be the wisest choice or possible in such situations. Knowing what is there and possible is.

Comment: While this question may not be useful to everyone, the point is that it is useful to the OP, and several others (including myself) voted to reopen.
I would think we would like to err on the side of inclusivity.

Comment: Not in favor of an open vote without some major edits. . Seems too subjective along the lines of “your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?“ “ at best this is a Wikipedia of possibilities which other sites do better than us.

Comment: @bmike That is quite a stretch, interpreting far past the context of my Question. I simply asked for a list of editor apps bundled by Apple with macOS, and shared the findings of my research up to that point. I am truly astounded that such a simple honest question causes so much consternation here. A simple bullet-list of any additional apps was all I expected. And LangLangC’s comments are exactly the education I'd hoped for.

Comment: I'm just one vote - there are many other people that can have a different opinion on what's on or off topic. we should probably move this all to [meta] or [chat] if there's discussion about on or off topic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you did ask "What other options for command-line text editors are built into macOS?" and `ed` was not mention in your OP, let me offer it as an addition to the list.

The manual page for [`ed`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ed.1.html) states:

> The **ed** utility is a line-oriented text editor.  It is used to create, display, modify and otherwise manipulate text files.

Comment: Well, reopened only to be closed again as a duplicate. At least `ed` wasn't mentioned in the duplicate. (Sorry, I just couldn't resist.) :)

Comment: Good answer. Thanks. Consider posting on linked Question

Comment: @Basil Bourque, Since you mentioned it, I did. Thanks.

Comment: POSIX conformance require `ed`, `ex`, and `vi` are available on the conforming OS.

Comment: @fd0 Can you cite documentation of that fact, about POSIX requiring certain editors? Interesting.

Comment: @BasilBourque- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/ie.html